# what am I (I will survive even when the world ends)

Tags: riddle

I have more legs than a human
No zoo can hold me no person can touch me.
I can live in space
I can live in -271
I can live in +150
I can not eat for decades
I will survive even when the world ends
I live in most foods you eat but you aren't even aware of me. (Yes even vegetables)

What am I?

Hint

> I am mostly found in moss

Hint

> I am not bacteria

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it isn't really puzzly - not wordplay/special interpretations of the lines is required, just simple looking up of directly stated facts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suspect you are a:

> tardigrade

Reason:

> All of those things listed are traits of a tardigrade.  8 legs, microscopic (can't be held in a zoo), have lived in space, temp ranges match that wiki page, have survived multiple mass extinctions. I wasn't aware that they're in foods, but it seems reasonable.

> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tardigrade